# Have to boot PC twice to get display signal / image

Tags: boot, memory, display

For quite some months now, I keep getting a "no signal" message on my display when booting my desktop PC every now and then. When pressing reset, the problem disappears and everything boots normally.

Setup:

- Ryzen 7 2700x
- AsRock fatal1ty x470
- 64GB DDR4 RAM (4 slots)
- GeForce RTX 2070
- Pop!_OS (Ubuntu) 22.04 LTS (not sure if this is a relevant fact since the problem already appears on BIOS boot-up)

Unfortunately, I can't remember changing anything recently. I did install a BIOS update some months ago, however I can't say for sure if this caused the issue.

Did anyone here face similar problems and knows a solution?

Comment: Hi @harrymc, thanks for the comment, however as stated before, I'm not using Windows.